# Wordpress Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, apache2

Last week, I moved the wordpress instance to new server. After that I frequently get 500 Internal Server Error. This error comes all of the sudden. The apache error log does not contain any fatal error messages but it contains PHP warning messages.

Whenever this error occurs, I restart the apache and the site is back to normal state. What may be the reason for this 500 Internal Server Error?

How does restarting apache solves this error? Only this site gets this error, other sites deployed to this server are working fine.

Comment: What warning do you get? any htaccess issues? what changes did you made while migrating?

Comment: I get the following message.
PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /var/www/xxx/wp-content/plugins/count-per-day/counter.php on line 1216
  I did not make any changes.

Comment: Disable your count-per-day plugin and then browse you site. Sometimes in wordpress plugins do malfunction.

Comment: Any other solution? Now the site is working fine. But suddenly and frequently I get this error.

Comment: I too have migrated a few of my site and faced these problems. Most of them are due to plugins.

Comment: Since obviously the plugin has a problem I'd guess you have a difference in requirement satisfaction for the plugin. Probably some math module or app isn't installed. It might make sense to take a lok at that line that throws the warning. What is done in there?

Comment: On viewing the statistics of this plugin, I get the same warning message. But this does not lead to Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why wordpress urls contained in the BD pointing to the url old, running this script in phpmyadmin can solve:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value,'old_site','new_site');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'old_site','new_site');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid,'old_site','new_site');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value,'old_site','new_site');
```

Also exist the possibility that your hosting account contains a folder with your username, in the wp_options table may be included, for example upload_path: "/home/[folder_old_id]/public_html/wp-content/uploads"

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value,'folder_old_id','folder_new_id');
```

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress internal server error, 500 Internal Server Error Solved!

firstly login admin dashboard in wordpress

1. go to setting
2. select option permalink
3. change option and select post url format in all option list and save it
4. check visit our page where error is come ...

Comment: Can you add some explanation? Why do you think that it solves the problem? Which parts where neccessary?